# CodeIgniter 3.1.3 Upload multiple files handle errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload multiple files at once.
I use in my form on this way:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
```

The problem is i want to validate each file before to do the proper upload on my config directory.

If someone upload 15 files at once and one file dosen`t have a valid size and/or type....i want to abort all the files upload and a give a error on form.
Al thinks are good but i cant do a check first (using codeigniter library upload)
I try this to verify if the files are valid but they already get uploaded in my folder file and i dont want this:

```
if ($_FILES['files']['name']['0'] != '') {
    $config['upload_path'] = 'docs/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$value) {
        $file_upload[$key] = array(
                'name'=>$_FILES['files']['name'][$key],
                'type'=>$_FILES['files']['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name'=>$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'=>$_FILES['files']['error'][$key],
                'size'=>$_FILES['files']['size'][$key]
            );
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($file_upload as $key=>$file) {
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $_FILES['file' . $key] = $file_upload[$key];
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file' . $key)) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $this->error['files_error'] = sprintf($this->upload->display_errors(),$_FILES['file' . $key]['name']);
                $this->error['error_warning'] = $this->lang->line('error_warning_form');
            } else {
                $this->error['files_error'] .= sprintf($this->upload->display_errors(),$_FILES['file' . $key]['name']);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to validate each files and if all files are ok, then upload them to my folder

P.S. Sorry for my english

Thanks for any help i will get

Comment: Please can you show error screenshot when you upload a file?

Comment: You're always going to have at least a temp folder where the files are indeed uploaded. This is why many people also apply client-side validation.

Comment: Is not a error when i upload files. My form is big. If any errors are in form (of any of the input field) user will see a error. User must select again the files for upload. Each time i verify the form and is not valid, the only way to check if files for upload are the right type is to use $this->upload->do_upload(). But every time i verify the files for upload i will have in my files directory file.pdf, file1.pdf,file3.pdf and so on. Only the last file will be also linked with my form in database. Until that function move files they are in /tmp/.  Is any way to use codeigniter for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by extend class upload. I use to do a new function called do_upload_check and i use all the data from do_upload but i remove the last row where the files was move from /tmp/ to my directory for files upload